# Reshape JSON with JQ

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

I'm trying to reshape a JSON file using JQ, and I can't seems to find the correct way to do it.

Basically I'm trying to turn some of the keys into values, and re-organize some parts of the JSON.

The source JSON is the following :

```
{
  "ABCC": {
    "pairs": {
      "CND": {
        "tsyms": {
          "BTC": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          },
          "ETH": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          }
        }
      },
      "ELF": {
        "tsyms": {
          "ETH": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          },
          "BTC": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "ACX": {
    "pairs": {
      "PLA": {
        "tsyms": {
          "AUD": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          },
          "USDT": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          }
        }
      },
      "BTC": {
        "tsyms": {
          "USDT": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          },
          "AUD": {
            "useless_variable1": "useless_value1",
            "useless_variable2": "useless_value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the expected JSON output would be something like that :

```
{
  "ABCC": {
    "pairs": [
      "CND/BTC",
      "CND/ETH",
      "ELF/ETH",
      "ELF/BTC"
    ]
  },
  "ACX": {
    "pairs": [
      "PLA/AUD",
      "PLA/USDT",
      "BTC/USDT",
      "BTC/AUD"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea how I could reach this result ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to a straightforward solution is to write a helper function for extracting the key/key strings:

```
# emit a stream of key1/key3 strings
def pairs:
  keys_unsorted[] as $k1
  | .[$k1][]
  | keys_unsorted[] as $k3
  | "\($k1)/\($k3)";
```

Now, thanks to jq's `|=` operator, the solution can be written simply as:

```
map_values(.pairs |= [pairs])
```